# JavaScript arrays - Finding the number of combinations of 2 elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I come from a Ruby background, which features an  `enumerable` class. In Ruby, I can easily find combinations of array elements.

```
array.combination(2).count
```

I know that JavaScript doesn't feature such built in functions, so I was wondering how I could implement this in JS. I was thinking something like

I have an array as follows

```
var numbers = [9,7,12]
var combos = []
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)  {
  combos.push([numbers[i], numbers[i+1])
}
```

By the way, the possible combos are

```
[9,7], [9,12] and [7,12]
```

so by calling the length function on this array, 3 would be returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does order matter? ie: [9,7] and [7,9], are they considered distinct?

Comment: I think that would be considered a `repeated combination`. Both of them consider the same two numbers, so they should be the same. I'm looking for all combinations of different numbers

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    for (var j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++)
        combos.push([numbers[i], numbers[j]]);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Looks like this is using multiple recursion. Thanks @JuniorCompressor

Comment: @JoshWinters This is just a nested for loop. No recursion

Comment: Sorry, I meant multiple iteration.

Comment: @JoshWinters: This is hardcoded for `2`. You wanted to implement Ruby's `combination()`, right?

Comment: You're right, this only works for 2. Learning how `combination(n)` works is intriguing

Answer (score 1):

Are you strictly talking about 2-combinations of the array or are you interested in a k-combinations solution?

Found this in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/axelpale/3118596)

```
function k_combinations(set, k) {
var i, j, combs, head, tailcombs;

if (k > set.length || k <= 0) {
    return [];
}

if (k == set.length) {
    return [set];
}

if (k == 1) {
    combs = [];
    for (i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
        combs.push([set[i]]);
    }
    return combs;
}

// Assert {1 < k < set.length}

combs = [];
for (i = 0; i < set.length - k + 1; i++) {
    head = set.slice(i, i+1);
    tailcombs = k_combinations(set.slice(i + 1), k - 1);
    for (j = 0; j < tailcombs.length; j++) {
        combs.push(head.concat(tailcombs[j]));
    }
}
return combs;
}
```

Comment: This question was specifically about combinations of 2 elements. But thanks, this could be useful too

Comment: You can modify this (actually make it less modular and more specific) to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive function, which should work for any number:

```
function combination(arr, num) {
  var r= [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
    if(num===1) r.push([arr[i]]);
    else {
      combination(arr.slice(i+1), num-1).forEach(function(val) {
        r.push([].concat(arr[i], val));
      });
    }
  }
  return r;
} //combination
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0pbn6zoL/)